# How do I compute recall and precision in OpenCV using Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on feature matching between two images using keypoints descriptors ( SIFT, SURF, BRIEF,...). So far, I've got the code that detects the keypoints, compares the  keypoints and finds the number of matches. I want to compare how well the descriptors perform using recall and precision that was suggested in a lot of papers.

How do I compute recall and precision in order to compare different image descriptors in OpenCV?

Comment: What are you doing with opencv? classification? detection? Please be more specific...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: I am working on feature matching between two images using keypoints descriptors ( SIFT, SURF, BRIEF,...). So far, I've got the code that detects the keypoints, compare keypoints and finds the number of matches. I want to compare how well the descriptors perform using recall and precision that was suggested in a lot of papers.

Comment: In order to calculate recall and precision you must know your ground truth i.e. if you find something you should compare it to the reference result and check if the match is ok.

Comment: Clarified the question...